# FIELDQUOTE = '"' not working for DateTime2 field using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, azure, dynamics-crm

[image]

I'm using Azure Synapse Analytics to create a view using the following SQL, the data above is from the account table and brought over using Synapse from D365 and its automatically created in Azure Synapse in csv format :

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Account
AS
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://tvrcrmsynapsedatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-yvrqa-unqfb7eeea818cc47be9935441a489da/account/*',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
        FIRSTROW = 1,
        FIELDQUOTE = '"'
    ) 
    with (
    [Id] uniqueidentifier 1, 
    [SINKCreatedon] DATETIME2(7) 2,
    [StateCode] BIGINT 4,
    [Name] VARCHAR(640) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 134,
     [primarycontactid] uniqueidentifier 63
    )
    AS [account]
```

Microsoft documentation saying to use FIELDQUOTE but I get an error for any DateTime2 field.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-single-csv-file

Error Message:
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row starting at byte offset 0 . .

My view can be created fine if I comment out the [SINKCreatedon] field. But I need to be able to bring back some of the datetime fields in quotes, has anyone come across this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Having date/time data in a regional format is just asking for trouble. Always use ISO 8601 for this (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`). SQL Server/Azure can produce this with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [mydatetimecolumn], 127)` (if you really need milliseconds precision `FORMAT` is more convenient, but much slower). If you can't change the input format, use `VARCHAR(...)` in your format specification instead, and apply a `CONVERT` in your outer `SELECT` (this should also be the solution to your quoting woes, incidentally).

Comment: @JeroenMostert its an out of the box datetime field from Dyanamics 365, so I dont have any control over it

Comment: A `DATETIME` has no format, and I really doubt Dynamics 365 stores every date/time value as a literal string. I can't see what process/query you're using to export the data, but almost certainly there is a way to export it with a specific format. If you just use defaults it's very well possible it ends up formatted as local time, but that's not the only way, unless someone somewhere made a big design error. On the other hand, if this value really *is* a string (i.e. there's not even a guarantee it's a valid date/time), then there's your answer: import it as a string.

Comment: @JeroenMostert its called a synapse link and created directly inside make.powerapps site and you cant control much using it. You just select the tables and it creates them in the Azure datalake. Thanks for the suggestion though